# Soapui - How to maintain session from login post request to get request

Tags: xml, rest, groovy, soapui

Im using soapui(5.2.1) for webservice testing , not able to hit the rest api-Get request followed by 
post request (authentication).

Below are the scritps that i have

1 Login(Post request) - Login

2 SetCookie - Groovyscript

3.GetBasic(Get request) - To get json output data

4.RunAll(Run all the teststep (Post request,SetCookie,Get request) )- Groovyscript

First request is working fine , tried to hit get request but throws "this requires http authentication".
I searched few blogs and written setcookie groovy script and below are the code.

```
def header = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Login").httpRequest.response.responseHeaders["Set-Cookie"]

header=header.toString()

start=header.indexOf("JSESSIONID=")

end=header.indexOf("; Path=")

testCaseProperty= header.substring(start,end)

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue( "JSESSIONID", testCaseProperty )

testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "JSESSIONID", testCaseProperty )

log.info "jsession id - "+testCaseProperty
```

After that at  GetBasic test step i set the header ${#TestSuite#JSESSIONID}.Then in RunAll 
script i have mentioned the step1,2,3 to run.

1.Login executed succesfully (username,password specified)
2.Set cookie executed succesfully
3.GetSystemdata(Get request) fails (throws "This requires http authentication")

But manually when i select the test case(check maintain session) and execute(Step1,2,3) it works fine

Please find the attached snap for the reference , can any one helpme on this please.

Note(Setcookie script set the cookie but it is not used by GetBasic get request)

Comment: This sounds like either you need to use HTTPS on the GET request and/or you need to set some credentials in the header of the request.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the reply , but get request show only http not https.Still should i change

Comment: Use your intuition here.  What did you get back from your login?  Were there any sort of credentials?  If so, you might need to include them in subsequent requests.

Comment: I have included cookie,username,password for the get request , but no result

Comment: Ok Tim ,actually the post response throws JSESSIONID,UNAMEIT.LOGOUT.SSO,UNAMEIT.LOGOUT.URL,UNAMEIT.SESSIONID .From this i take jsession id alone with user name and password for get request is that enough

Answer (score 0):

For basic authentication, you need to turn on "Maintain HTTP Session" in the TestCase Options. This is described in the official documentation [here](https://www.soapui.org/soapui-projects/form-based-authentication.html).